# Cookie Not Showing In Common.php Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel-5.1

I've a cookie in my browser and It is showing in any other controller that $_COOKIE['etc'] is set. But when I'm going to check it in my App/Functions/Common.php it is showing that the $_COOKIE['etc'] undefined at the same time when i'm checking it on any other controller it is set.
Here is my Common.php Code

```
 <?php 

    namespace App\Functions;
    use App\Model\ModelCategory;
    use App\Model\ModelProduct;
    use App\Model\ModelBrand;
    use App\Model\ModelStore;
    use App\Model\ModelWishlist;
    use App\Model\ModelProduct_Mapping;
    use Session;

    use DB;
    use Config;
    use Input;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;

    class Common
    {
                public static function get_wishlist_products()
            {

            $data['breadcrum']= "<a href='".url()."'>Home</a> > <a href='".url()."/wishlist/'>Wishlist</a>";
            if(isset($_COOKIE['etc'])){
                $cookie =  $_COOKIE['etc'];
                $get_product_ids = ModelWishlist::check_session_key_exist($cookie);
                $data['get_listing_header_wishlist'] = ModelProduct_Mapping::wishlist_products_detail($get_product_ids);
                }

            return $data;
            }
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. We have to use the laravel defined methods to set and get the cookie otherwise it won't work.

```
 class WishlistController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $wishlist = new ModelWishlist;
        $check_existance = Session::get('product_id');
        if(!isset($check_existance)){
            $check_existance = array();
            }
        if(!in_array($id,$check_existance))
        {
            Cookie::queue('user_session_id', Session::getId());

            //setcookie('user_session_id', Session::getId());
            Session::push('product_id',$id);
            Session::save();
            $wishlist->pw_wl_product_id =  $id;
            $wishlist->pw_wl_session_cookie_id =  Session::getId();
            $wishlist->save();
        }
    }

    public function show_wishlists()
    {
        $data = Common::common_function();
        $data['breadcrum']= "<a href='".url()."'>Home</a> > <a href='".url()."/wishlist/'>Wishlist</a>";

        if(Cookie::has('user_session_id') == Session::getId()   ){
            $cookie =  Cookie::get('user_session_id');
            $get_product_ids = ModelWishlist::check_session_key_exist($cookie);

            $data['get_listing'] = ModelProduct_Mapping::wishlist_products_detail($get_product_ids);    
        }           
        return view('wishlistpage')->with('data',$data);
    }
}
```